# UWP and .NET Core

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-core, windows-mobile

I am new to the .NET Framework. I understand that UWP (apps will be able to run on all Windows 10 devices with one application package and one code base) became possible after .NET Core was introduced.

My question is how and what technologies were used to build apps for Windows phone or tablet or Xbox before UWP came to existence?

Comment: Have a look at Xamarin, it's cross platform framework to build UI apps for Androind, iOS, UWP and other mobile platforms, based on Mono runtime. Not sure about XBox

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this is for the mobile only, right?

Comment: Afaik, you can compile it to UWP and WPF, using PCL and .NET standard support

Comment: For the record, UWP apps don't use .NET Core. Until version 3, .NET Core is/was mainly a cross-platform (Linux, macOS and Windows) framework for server-side applications. Before UWP, you could for example use Silverlight to develop for the Windows Phone.